# How to animate background image on hover with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I have a square div with a diagonal image as the background.

When I hover over the div, I want the diagonal background image to expand, as shown below.

[image]

I have used [CSS to accomplish this](https://jsfiddle.net/vavjnrv7/1/), but I want the transition to animate instead of "snapping".

```
<div class="content-box medium-box corner">
   <div>
   </div>
</div>

* { 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;}

.content-box {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: url(http://keithdonegan.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/corner-bg.svg) 0px 0px;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: all .8s;
}

.content-box:hover {
   background-size: 550px 550px;
   background-position: 0px 0px;
}
```

I would also the like background image to animate back to the original position when the cursor leaves the div.

[Link to the test site](http://tinylink.net/LllH4).

Any ideas?

Comment: Just provided a pure css solution for this. no images, no jQuery, no js :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure CSS solution for the problem as was describe in the question.

Notice that if you HAVE TO use a background image, it is possible to assign it to the `::before` element, and still animate using the same CSS, without the use of js/jQuery...

As a best practice, always strive to keep your HTML as clean as possible (no redundant elements just for animations...), and try to avoid loading unneeded resources (images, scripts). It will keep your page much faster, and your code much easier to maintain.

```css
#frame {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  border: solid 1px red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#frame::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: -100px;
  width:100px;
  height:0;
  border-color: black;
  border-top: solid 100px black;
  border-right: solid 100px transparent;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-left: none;
  transition: left 1s;
}

#frame:hover::before {
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="frame"></div>
```

Comment: Also @KeithDonegan, if it works for you, accepting the answer is the right way to go :-)

Comment: This is a nice solution but the issue is `"How to animate background image on hover with JQuery?"` and on your answer you not use a background image. Effectively without background image this work very fine

Comment: Using the background image in this case, is part of the (wrongly picked) solution that the guy chose. I think it's much better to avoid loading the unnecessary image, and the unneeded js code.  My solution could just as easily be adapted to use background image instead (still with no js...). Anyway, thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @RonenCypis Lots of ways to skin a cat my friend. Image is ~1k. Thanks for the alternative answer anywho but yeah.

Comment: @KeithDonegan even a ~1k image can sometimes not load... network stuff..

Answer (score 0):

you can make the transition animate with pure CSS.

To say if it is possible in your case I would need your code.

But check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) for more information.

**EDIT:** use

`background-size: 250px 250px;`

instead of cover and the maigc is done

**EDIT2:**

```
.content-box {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: url(http://keithdonegan.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/corner-bg.svg) 0px 0px;
  background-size: 250px 250px;
  transition: all 5s;
}

.content-box:hover {
   background-size: 550px 550px;
   background-position: 0px 0px;
   transition: all 5s;
}
```

Comment: Not quite Marcel. I also want it to animate back, and not "snap" back when hovered away from the div. Thanks anywho

Comment: then you ofc need to add the "transition: all .8s;" also on your hover.... see edit

Answer (score 0):

If you add center center and easing for your animation it's fine. Please try:

```css
* { 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;}

.content-box {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: url(http://keithdonegan.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/corner-bg.svg) 0px 0px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition:  all 0.8s ease 0s;
  transition:  all 0.8s ease 0s;
}

.content-box:hover {
   background-size: 350% 350%;
   background-position: 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-box medium-box corner">
   <div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah I did originally have this the same way but on Safari it's not smooth

Comment: I have add -webkit- for transition. Please try my update.